# Google reCaptcha Verification

Tags: recaptcha

I'm a little confused by the opening paragraph of this article: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

When you use the third method to validate (i.e. the `data-callback' attribute), does this mean that there's no longer a need to POST to https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify from the back end? Is this essentially a 100% client-side captcha?

Answer (score 0):

It means you would post with ajax and when you get your callback if its successful or not then you can have a Javascript function to allow the submit/post or whatever action you need to do. I use the callback to allow the login button to submit and if it has not been completed then the button remains disabled. You will still need to submit your challenge to google so they can verify if it is successful. Here is a simplified example.

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" id="login" data-callback="captcha_filled"
             data-expired-callback="captcha_expired" data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></div>

function captcha_filled() {
    $("#submitLogin").prop('disabled', false);
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't just executing `grecaptcha.getResponse()` achieve the same? As far as I can tell, if the user forgets to check the captcha or fails the challenge, then `grecaptcha.getResponse()` will not have a value. In that case, what's the point of using your own AJAX post?

Comment: I did up a test and it seems you are right. If the challenge is not completed and `grecaptcha.getResponse()` is called it will return null and it will return a value if successful. In your question you mention the third method as the data-callback which is what confused me but that's not what this method is doing either. You can use the above call to verify your challenge but the data-callback is just to perform any type of function when completed. Here is some more info on the [Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#js_api).